# Error while try to connect table on DB2 using Python (SQL0332N)

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm connecting to DB2-LUW database using Python 3.7 and some queries  get error : "SQL0332N  Character conversion from the source code page "1252" to the target code page "874" is not supported.***".

First I try to test the connection of Python to the database on DB2 by recreating a new table.

I insert 1 record and read it back. When I read the inserted row, I get the error.

Results in interactive python:

```
import ibm_db_dbi as dbi

print(dbi.__version__)
3.0.2

conn = dbi.connect("DATABASE=<db>;HOSTNAME=<hostname>;PORT=<port>;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=<user>;PWD=<pwd>;", "", "")

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('create table ibm_db_tst (col1 int)')
Out[5]: True

c.execute('insert into ibm_db_tst values(2)')
Out[6]: True

c.execute('select col1 from ibm_db_tst')
Out[7]: True

print(c.fetchone())
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Users\2400566\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dbi.py",
> line 1449, in _fetch_helper
> row = ibm_db.fetch_tuple(self.stmt_handler)
>
> SQLCODE=-332lumn information cannot be retrieved: [IBM][CLI
> Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0332N  Character conversion from the source code
> page "1252" to the target code page "874" is not supported.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
print(c.fetchone())

File "C:\Users\2400566\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dbi.py", line 1475, in fetchone
row_list = self._fetch_helper(1)

File "C:\Users\2400566\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dbi.py", line 1456, in _fetch_helper
raise self.messages[len(self.messages) - 1]

***SQLCODE=-332_dbi::Error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0332N  Character conversion from the source code page "1252" to the target code page "874" is not supported.***

I'm not sure what's wrong? Need advice.

my Python version is Python 3.7.7 running on Window 10 PC x64

DB2 is on Windows server 2012 x64 .

DB2 version is DB2 v11.1.0.1527.

Database territory : GB
Database code page : 1252
Database code set : 1252
Database country/region code : 44

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that your database has one code page and the environment another, that the driver does not understand how to convert between. 874 seems to be ISO 8859-11 which seems related to Thai. Is that deliberate?

Comment: Please create (or alter) a system environment variable `DB2CODEPAGE` and set its value to 1208.  You may need to __reboot__ your windows workstation. Then retry the python script.  You should also menion your python version and bitness, and the exact Windows edition and bitness.

Comment: @Lennart , I'm not sure is it deliberate or not ? Need to confirm with IT person who help me set up this DB.

Comment: @mao , my Python version is Python 3.7.7 running on Window 10 PC x64 and DB2 is on Windows server 2012 x64 and DB2 version is DB2 v11.1.0.1527. I'll try to change DB2CODEPAGE

Comment: @mao I got  more 1 question, why this problem happened only with Python? From the same window 10 Pc if connect to this DB2 I can create table insert update the table by using SQLworkbench/J. Any advise, why only Python is dependency.

Comment: @PreuttiP . Do not add new facts in comments, instead edit your question to add new information.  Comments are not searchable and can be deleted. The SQLworkbench/j  is a java application (uses the jdbc driver),  but Python uses the ODBC/CLI driver, different code, different requirements, different configuration.

Comment: @mao thanks for the tips and thank to help adding additional information into original question.

Comment: @mao please advise for 1 more question, error message said the source code page is "1252" and the target code page is "874". And any reason to change DB2CODEPAGE to 1208. Kindly advise. Thank you.

Comment: Use the Db2 Knowledge Centre to get basic answers to simple configuration questions like this.

Comment: @PreuttiP, What I meant was "do you need that codepage, or can you change it"? Anyhow, I think mao pointed you in the right direction

Comment: Please, provide the `code-page`,and `territory` ( `db2 get db cfg for <dbname>`) used to create this database. Per the error, it seems it has been created using codepage 874,  which is related to [Thailand locale](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/r0004565.html). 
Was it intentional ? Your windows seems to be configured for regular Latin 1252 codepage. If you want your db to host thai characters,  the db should have been created as unicode db (codeset = utf-8) at db creation time.

Comment: @SamuelPizarro edited to add information you've suggested. DB code page is set to 1252 and I have no requirement to use Thai Character in my database.

Comment: @mao is there any alternative to fix this problem without Rebooting server? Plan to maintenance the server is at the year end.

Comment: As explained in docs, and as I mentioned above, this variable is a workstation-side (client side) setting. No need to change Db2-server or database. It takes seconds to apply or rolllback this environment variable. A reboot is not essential, but will ensure that all processes involved will pick up the new environment variable (but they can be manually bounced also).

Comment: ah,  now I realized its was a fetch operation,  so the conversion was in the opposite direction (from server to your workstation). So, for some reason the python driver wants to convert it to codepage 874. What locale do you have in you windows-10 workstation reginal settings ?   Besides that,  I would also try @mao 's suggestion by forcing DB2CODEPAGE env variable in your client setup.

Answer (score 0):

In case that your python script is using db2dsdriver to connect to database on server, try to set the DisableUnicode keyword to 0 to enforce unicode code page (i.e. 1208) on Windows.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.config.doc/doc/r0054636.html

Answer (score 0):

Set an environment variable DB2CODEPAGE to 1208.

Credit to user @mao for saying this in a comment. Adding it as an answer for better visibility.